# Paste down as far as there are filled cells in parallel row

Tags: vba, excel

To be honest, I'm very fresh to VBA and am probably missing something very easy here. I've been reading about different kinds of loops and ways to end the whole macro if a cell is empty but I've had no luck bringing these ideas together.

Basically, there is this portion of my code that selects a range, copies and then selects down to paste. This has just been blowing up my computer and making it take forever. I would love to find a way to make this only copy down for as many rows are there are items in the parallel row in column 1.

I figure I could either make it only select x number of rows down before it runs the paste function, or I could run a loop that checks column 1 before it pastes each row. How far off am I?

```
Range("AA2:AE2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("AE2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("W2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Range("AA2:AE2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Look from the bottom up for the last populated row in column A.

```
dim lr as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    lr = .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
    .range("AA2:AE" & lr).filldown
end with
```

I've saved you one operation by switching to .FillDown from .Copy & . Paste.

Comment: This is a nice efficient solution.